Is there a way to make a transforming platform do damage in unity
I am working on a 2d platformer game in unity for a school project, and for one of the mechanics we have a sort of heating element that turns on and off after a certain amount of time. I currently have the turning on and off part from scraps of code that I found online, but I can't seem to make it do damage to my character.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls;

public class heatPlatforms : MonoBehaviour
{



    public List<Sprite> spritesToSwap; // contains all the sprites to loop through
    public float Speed = 0f;
    IEnumerator SwapSprites()
    {
        int spriteIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spritesToSwap[spriteIndex];
            // ^ replace the sprite
            spriteIndex++;
            if (spriteIndex == spritesToSwap.Count) spriteIndex = 0;
            // ^ loop back to first sprite
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Speed); // adjust this time as desired
        }
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Starts the loop
        StartCoroutine(SwapSprites());

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        //when character hits the proper sprite, then you take damage.
        PlayerCharacter player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>();

         //sprite that does damage should be second sprite in the array.
         if (spritesToSwap.Count == 1)
         {
            if (player != null)
            {
                player.ChangeHealth(-1);

            }
        }
    }


    //Can not do the code below because triggers have nothing for character to stand on. Will   only go through the sprite.

    //void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    //{
    //    PlayerCharacter controller = other.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>();

    //    if (spritesToSwap.Count == 1)
    //    {

    //        if (controller != null)
    //        {
    //            controller.ChangeHealth(-1);
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

} 


You made a mistake in the condition if (spritesToSwap.Count == 1).

As mentioned in the comments it makes no sense to check for the amount of sprites in the list
if (spritesToSwap.Count == 1)

this will (in your case) basically be a constant value and according to your comment there will be at least 2 elements anyway.
Move spriteIndex to class scope and check that instead
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

// moved to class scope so other methods have access
private int spriteIndex;

// Btw to keep things simple: Start itself can be a coroutine 
// so you can save some implementation effort and reduce complexity here
IEnumerator Start()
{
    if(!spriteRenderer) spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    while (true)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = spritesToSwap[spriteIndex];
        // increase by one with positive wrap around
        spriteIndex = (spriteIndex + 1) % spritesToSwap.Count;
    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Speed); // adjust this time as desired
    }
}

and then
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
     //sprite that does damage should be second sprite in the array.
     // moving this check up because a simple int equality is way cheaper to do first
     if(spriteIndex != 1) return;

     //when character hits the proper sprite, then you take damage.
    // making use of better API to reduce complexity 
     if(!other.gameObject.TryGetComponent<PlayerCharacter>(out var player)) return;

     player.ChangeHealth(-1);
}

